# Explanation for PHP preg_match_all matches array print_r

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following usage for `preg_match_all`:

```
$re = "/^(-\\w+\\s*.*)\\n*$/um"; 
$str = "-Give on result\n-Second new text\n-The third text\n\nAnother paragraph without list.\n\n-New list here"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

The output of `print_r($matches)` has a weird array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => -Give on result
            [1] => -Second new text
            [2] => -The third text

            [3] => -New list here
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => -Give on result
            [1] => -Second new text
            [2] => -The third text
            [3] => -New list here
        )

)
```

Here I'm talking about the array of index `0` and the visually blank line appeared in the `print_r()` output. Indeed, this question may be related to [**my another question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629689/regex-starts-with-x-or-x-prefixed-or-suffixed/30629749#30629749) about [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) and I need to know why the two arrays are different? An online demo is found [here](http://ideone.com/wezcz3)

Comment: There's a space after `"The third text` because it's still catching a `\n`

Comment: @Darren I don't think that, because if there is another caching it should be demonstrated in new array key and also, if so, why the second array does not has the blank line?!

Comment: Look at what `var_dump($matches)` shows, it has more detail

Answer (score 0):

try this so easy to make that

```
<?php

//$re = "/^(-\\w+\\s*.*)\\n*$/um"; 
$re = "/^(\\h*(?:-|&)\\h*\w+\\s*.*)\\n*$/um";
$str = "-Give on result\n-Second new text\n-The third text\n\nAnother paragraph without list.\n\n-New list here"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
$i = 0;


    echo "<ul>".preg_replace_callback($re,function($mt){return "<li>".$mt[1]."</li>";},$str)."</ul>";



$re = array_filter(preg_split('/\n/', $str));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($re);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to replicate this. I usually use this tool https://www.debuggex.com/r/AXpFXcR-ioMLhLCd that explains the Regex conditions in a fancier way.

So far, I think the code evals the regex and only one `\n` is catched, so the next one passes directly to the output. But I'm trying to confirm this behavior.